# flutter how to pass a value when called statefulwidget class

Tags: flutter, dart

I create StatefulWidget class using 'stful' to build it and i need to pass special value that i created in this class. I did it with common class like this

```
class CheckListPoint{
  bool correctly = true;
  bool passed = false;
  String requirement = '';
  CheckListPoint(this.correctly,this.passed,this.requirement);
}
```

when i call this class  CheckListPoint() i need to pass values,
how can I make it so that when calling the 'SomeClass', I also need to pass the value to the 'SomeClass' parameter?

```
class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const SomeClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SomeClassState createState() => _SomeClassState();
}

class _SomeClassState extends State<SomeClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
```

}

Comment: Do you like to pass `CheckListPoint` object or just  string/variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add variable on widget like the way did on class. Then you can pass those data, you can use named constructor(are optional parameter by default) or just constructor

```
class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final String parameter1;
  final int id;
  final List<int> numbers;
  final CheckListPoint checkListPoint;

  SomeClass({
    Key? key,
    required this.parameter1,
    required this.id,
    required this.numbers,
    required this.checkListPoint,
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  //* Or
  SomeClass(
  //   Key? key,
  //   this.parameter1,
  //   this.id,
  //   this.numbers,
  //   this.checkListPoint,
  // ) : super(key: key);



  @override
  _SomeClassState createState() => _SomeClassState();
}

class _SomeClassState extends State<SomeClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(" id ${widget.id}"),
    );
  }
}
```

And you use these data, you can use `widget.parameter1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final CheckListPoint x;
  const SomeClass({Key? key , required this.x}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SomeClassState createState() => _SomeClassState();
}

class _SomeClassState extends State<SomeClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //while accessing x use widget.x
    return Container();

  }
```